# Форма добавления поста на сайт

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть php страница, с которой я добавляю данные в базу mysql, при помощи обычного текстбокса textarea. Естественно этот вариант крайне примитивный, по многим причинам, будет это перенос на следующую строку, или выделение части текста жирным... В моем случае:

```
<textarea name="mess" rows="50" cols="80" maxlength="5000"></textarea>
```

1. Как правильно называются такие формы ввода? (Нужно для гугления.)
2. Посоветуйте пару решений.

Comment: Что вы именно хотите, объясните понятнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вариант не примитивный а самый обычный, можно передавать текст через текстарею а можно отправлять текст аяксом, а если вам надо редактировать текст хтмл тегами, то вам надо установить редактор [wysiwyg](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG). Суть их работы проста: при выделении текста яваскрипт обрамляет нужный участок тегами, например для жирного текста и уже в таком виде подставляет в текстарею для сабмита в базу

Comment: да, что то вроде редактора текста, что бы я мог ввести текст, как скажем в простейшем текстовом редакторе.

Comment: там на википедии внизу, перечень самых популярных js редакторов для сайтов, почитайте и выбирайте, но самый популярные это TinyMCE и CKeditor

Answer (score 0):

Не считаю себя специалистом в этой области, но вот несколько советов:

- Что бы сохранить переносы строки при выводе на страницу используйте РНР функцию [nl2br](http://www.php.su/functions/?nl2br) (возвращает строку string, в которой перед каждым переводом строки вставлен '< br />')
- Для жирного текста используйте ХТМЛ теги <strong></strong>. По аналогии так же можно реализовать курсив, список и т.д. Ну или используйте свои обозначения и перед вставкой в базу или на выходе заменяйте их на хтмл теги.
- Реализуйте только набор тех функций, которые Вам нужны. Обратите внимание на функцию [htmlentities](http://www.php.su/functions/?htmlentities)